# How to use pickled file as dataset for keras

Tags: machine-learning, pickle, theano, keras, mnist

I have build my own dataset for digit classification and it worked well with convolutional network model developed by lisa lab ([Here](https://github.com/lisa-lab/DeepLearningTutorials/blob/8e9db1a5494ca22ee01f53da34df26ea766ebaee/code/convolutional_mlp.py)). I wanted to visualize the weights and i wanted to do it through keras.

Keras documentation tries to load mnist data like this:

```
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
```

But i want my pickled dataset to load instead of mnist default data. Where does mnist module for keras load it's dataset ? And, how can i pass my own dataset instead of that to use mnist module from keras ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can get a lot of info about this method by reading the source: https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/datasets/mnist.py

In this case, the dataset is a pickle file loaded from an Amazon S3 bucket.

You could write a copy of this function and use it yourself to load up a different pickled dataset.

Comment: I have already found the local file (/usr/local/lib/python 2.7/dist-packages/keras/datasets/mnist.py), I can modify it with my dataset location. 
But, which turns out to be a problem is "__init__.py". Each directory has __init__.py but loading mnist data gives:
`from keras.datasets import mnist
ImportError: No module named datasets`
keras directory already has a directory named 'datasets' and __init__.py is present. I don't know why this isn't working.